# Organizing Geopackage similarly to structure of geodatabase

Tags: geopackage, feature-dataset

I've been looking all over the Internet if there is a way to organize a geopackage similar to a geodatabase, that is, to create multiple groups (similar to feature datasets in a gdb) within the geopackage. My knowledge on its use is a bit limited so it would be great if someone gave me some input.

What I'm trying to do is to create different groups (like feature datasets) within a geopackage, so when I open it, it contains all my groups in a single gpkg.

Answer (score 6):

There is no native support in placing database tables into groups in GeoPackage. GeoPackage is a SQLite database and the schema in SQLite is stored into table "sqlite_master" https://www.sqlite.org/schematab.html.

> Every SQLite database contains a single "schema table" that stores the
> schema for that database. The schema for a database is a description
> of all of the other tables, indexes, triggers, and views that are
> contained within the database. The schema table looks like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE sqlite_schema(   
    type text,
    name text,
    tbl_name text,
    rootpage integer,
    sql text
 );
```

So there is not any usable field for grouping in sqlite_master.

The GeoPackage standard defines a metadata table "gpkg_contents" that contains a list of spatial tables.

```
CREATE TABLE gpkg_contents (
table_name TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
data_type TEXT NOT NULL,
identifier TEXT UNIQUE,
description TEXT DEFAULT '',
last_change DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%fZ','now')),
min_x DOUBLE,
min_y DOUBLE,
max_x DOUBLE,
max_y DOUBLE,
srs_id INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT fk_gc_r_srs_id FOREIGN KEY (srs_id) REFERENCES gpkg_spatial_ref_sys
(srs_id)
);
```

Not a place for groups in that table either. However, it is possible for GeoPackage clients to present the tables in groups if the tables are named like "groupA_table1" but then the one who creates the tables must know what the client awaits. Clients that are not grouping aware would show the tables as usual.

It is also not really possible to store the layers in GeoPackage so that they would open in a certain order because the sqlite_master and gpkg_contents tables are not made to support such usage and users must not edit and sort those tables directly.