# Create something similar to feature dataset in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geopackage, feature-dataset

I have data in the format of an ArcGIS feature dataset (hydrology data). I want to make similar to feature dataset in QGIS (create a feature dataset in GeoPackage). How can I do it?

Comment: What ArcGIS format?

Comment: do you want to convert the existing data or start from the beginning?

Comment: I have data I want to convert. I want to save all the data in GeoPakage. but in the format of feature dataset (so I have category and every one have samples

Comment: Did you see this thread?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434778/can-i-organize-a-geopackage-similarly-to-the-structure-of-a-geodatabase

Comment: perfect!thank you